# Spark SQL - Aggregate collections?

Tags: apache-spark, aggregation

Let's say I have 2 data frames.

DF1 may have values {3, 4, 5} in column A of various rows.

DF2 may have values {4, 5, 6} in column A of various rows.

I can aggregate these into a set of distinct elements using distinct_set(A), assuming all those rows fall into the same grouping.

At this point I have a set in the resulting data frame.  Is there anyway to aggregate that set with another set?  Basically, if I have 2 data frames resulting from the first aggregation, I want to be able to aggregate their results.

Comment: you should provide an example of input and expected output. It sounds like this can be done using explode followed by another collect_set, or by an UDAF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While explode and collect_set could solve this, it made more sense just to write a custom aggregator to merge the sets themselves.  The structure underlying them is a WrappedArray.

```
case class SetMergeUDAF() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

  def deterministic: Boolean = false

  def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("input", ArrayType(LongType)) :: Nil)

  def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(StructField("buffer", ArrayType(LongType)) :: Nil)

  def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(LongType)

  def initialize(buf: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buf(0) = mutable.WrappedArray.empty[LongType]
  }

  def update(buf: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    if (!input.isNullAt(0)) {
      val result : mutable.WrappedArray[LongType] = mutable.WrappedArray.empty[LongType]
      val x = result ++ (buf.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0).toSet ++ input.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0).toSet).toArray[Long]
      buf(0) = x
    }
  }

  def merge(buf1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buf2: Row): Unit = {
    val result : mutable.WrappedArray[LongType] = mutable.WrappedArray.empty[LongType]
    val x = result ++ (buf1.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0).toSet ++ buf2.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0).toSet).toArray[Long]
    buf1(0) = x
  }

  def evaluate(buf: Row): Any = buf.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[LongType]](0)
}
```